# Declaratively defined property values don't work in Polymer LitElement

Tags: polymer

Declaratively defined properties won't update element's property.

Example:

```
<my-elem myvalue="test"></my-elem>

  static get properties() {
    return {
      myvalue: String  //The value of this property doesn't update to "test"
    }
```

Also reflectToAttribute doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problems in updating values of declarated properties and reflectToAttribute are related, I believe.

If you add following codes to your element, then the syncronization between property and attribute will work:

```
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name == "myvalue") this.myvalue = newValue; //change in attribute is updated to property
  }

  _render({ myvalue }) {
    renderAttributes(this, {
      'myvalue': myvalue  //value of property is updated to attribute 
    });

    return html`
      <div>something...</div>
    `;
  }
```